# what is the porpose of print(file.read())

Tags: python

the code works perfectly fine but when I delete the last line which is `print(file.read())`
I thought that it only **reads** the file but without it, it doesn't even **write**.

```
user = input("user name: ")

file = open(user + ".txt", "r+")
print(file.read())

my_string = input("enter data: ")
file.writelines(my_string + "\n")

print(file.read())
```

Comment: Are you trying to append to, or overwrite the current file contents?

Comment: wanted to append. I know the "a" (append method) but this code works really fine and I didn't want to change. any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, that’s what I recommend :p I actually haven’t tested it, so I will do that and get back to you ASAP

Comment: Also I’m guessing this isn’t representative of your actual program? It would be nice to have some more context. In particular, I was wondering if the current contents of the file need to be read in order to determine the new value to append.

Answer (score 3):

Use [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) to handle files! You forgot to close the file, which never would have been a problem in the first place.

```py
user = input("user name: ")
with open(f'{user}.txt', 'r+') as file_1:
    print(file_1.read())
    my_string = input("enter data: ")
    file_1.write(my_string)
    print(file_1.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I entirely understand the question, but here's my best attempt at it -

The open() function returns a file object which can used to read, write and modify file.

In order to actually access the contents of the file, you'll need to call the read method on the file object.

Make sure that you call file.close() when you're done modifying the file.

Comment: thanks the problem was the file.close(), I didn't use it and print(file.read()) was kinda doing that job.

Comment: I don't know how but it works fine with either of these at the end of the code.